# Mechanisms responsible for absorption loss in the Ionosphere

Tags: electromagnetism, atmospheric-science, space, antennas, radar

I have been given a task at my university of helping with calculating some link budgets for satelites. The work I usually do limits to transmitters and receivers located within the troposphere, while here I have been asked to research potential mechanisms responsible for losses in Ionosphere on top of the Free Space Path Loss.

So far what I have been trying to do some literature review, and stumbled across are the following definitions:

-Depolarisation Loss

-Auroral Absoprtion

-Polar Cap Absorption

My questions here are:

1. Are those three different types of absorptions, and should the losses be added here.
2. Is there anything else that will attenuate my signal in this region of the atmosphere? (Excluding Free Space path Loss of course). For example in the troposphere we have rain fade and water/oxygen attenuation which have large effects on communication on certain frequencies (etc. 22 GHz or 60 GHz). I am wondering if something similar happens in Ionosphere.
3. Can someone recommend some good literature on this topic in general, something not very technical would be a good start.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Matlab now has a satellite toolbox that includes a link budget calculator. Freeflyer is a different software package that has some orbital mechanics mission planning and link budget capability. It has a university program. The matlab calcultor seemed to have a lot of inputs, but I haven’t looked at it in detail.